# Rewriting a GET URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter to create a search page. I'd like to rewrite a GET url to work with CI.

Example

```
http://mysite.com/en/search?search=widgets
```

becomes

```
http://mysite.com/en/search/widgets
```

I thought I could do this in the routes.php, but it doesn't seem to grab the stuff after the ?. So now i'm thinking as a rewrite in .htaccess. Is this a good idea? What would the rewrite rule be?

Comment: Before you get too comfortable with your new solution, try using quotes (for example) in your search term. CI will throw a fatal error, even if you are encoding them. With `$_GET` this will not happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use only the CI routing protocol. Anyway if you want to use .htaccess is this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^en/search/([a-z]+)  /en/search?search=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$route['en/search/(:any)'] = "en/search/$1";
```

What is basically does is remap anything with /en/search/something to en class , search method and the search query will be passed as parameter .

using :any is not generally recommended, but you can also use custom regex if you want to be more specific regarding the characters that you want to allow.

Comment: Why is using (:any) not recommended? The characters allowed are already restricted by the `$config['permitted_uri_chars']`

Answer (score 0):

```
$searchtext = $this->url->segment(2);
```

should get the value "widget" in codeigniter. (Sorry if I got the question wrong).